# Viewing Esri ASCII Raster file in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-ascii-raster

i have some problem viewing an ascii file in a structured way in arcGIS.

i have used IDL ENVI too to solve this issue but all data is not displayed.

This link has the files:
https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0#folders/0B8iAKVklcaMUVU5qY2NNVFBRbDQ

Comment: What is the problem?  How did you use ENVI to "solve the issue"?  What do you mean by "all data is not displayed"? (this begs for a screen shot)  Since ASCII is an exchange format, but not a display one, what format did you change to, and how?

Answer (score 1):

To see this work create a test [Esri ASCII Raster format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Esri_ASCII_raster_format/009t0000000z000000/) file (C:\temp\test.asc) with the contents below:

```
ncols 4
nrows 3
xllcorner 0
yllcorner 0
cellsize 1
nodata_value -999
1 2 3 4
4 2 3 3
3 2 2 1
```

To create a raster dataset from the ASCII raster file use the parameters below in the [ASCII To Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000002s000000) tool or just copy/paste it into the Python window and run it from there.

```
arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion("C:/temp/test.asc","C:/temp/testRaster","INTEGER")
```

It will probably add to ArcMap automatically, or if not, just do that manually to display it.

If this test works and your ASCII file does not then check using a text editor that your ASCII file has all the parts described in the [Esri ASCII Raster format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Esri_ASCII_raster_format/009t0000000z000000/).